# How to sum all values with index greater than X?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this series:

```
>>> s = pd.Series({1:10,2:5,3:8,4:12,5:7,6:3})
>>> s
1    10
2     5
3     8
4    12
5     7
6     3
```

I want to sum all the values for which the index is greater than X. So if e.g. X = 3, I want to get this:

```
>>> X = 3
>>> s.some_magic(X)
1    10
2     5
3     8
>3    22
```

I managed to do it in this rather clumsy way:

```
lt = s[s.index.values <= 3]
gt = s[s.index.values > 3]
gt_s = pd.Series({'>3':sum(gt)})
lt.append(gt_s)
```

and got the desired result, but I believe there should be an easier and more elegant way... or is there?

Comment: you can just do `s.loc[4:].sum()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s.groupby(np.where(s.index > 3, '>3', s.index)).sum()
```

Or,

```
s.groupby(s.index.to_series().mask(s.index > 3, '>3')).sum()
Out: 
1     10
2      5
3      8
>3    22
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series({1: 10, 2: 5, 3: 8, 4: 12, 5: 7, 6: 3})
iv = s.index.values

print s[iv <= 3].append(pd.Series({'>3': s[iv > 3].sum()}))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit nicer way to sum, but still doesn't solve the clumsy part of creating a series and 'manually' appending it.

Comment: @soungalo Ah, ok, I missed that part, edited my answer