# How to sum all values with one index greater than X in MultiIndexed Datarfame, grouping on the other indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I am trying to do the exact same thing as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125695/how-to-sum-all-values-with-index-greater-than-x) but with a MultiIndexed Pandas DataFrame. I've been trying to adapt the answer to the other post so that it would work with my DataFrame but without any luck.

Currently I have the following DataFrame where `target`, `wt` and `ms` are in the index:

```
                percent
target  wt  ms  
g1      2   1   2
            2   5
            ... ...
            620 0.003
            630 0.005
... ... ... ... ... 
g9      8   1   4
            2   8
            ... ...
            470 0.005
            480 0.004
```

I need to limit the range of `ms` to some number, say 12, and sum up the values in the `percent` column where `ms>12`, grouped on the indices `target` and `wt`.

The outcome I want would look something like this:

```
                percent
target  wt  ms  
g1      2   1   2
            2   5
            ... ...
            >12 5.4
... ... ... ... ... 
g9      8   1   4
            2   8
            ... ...
            >12 7.3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create boolean mask by level `ms` by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) compared by scalar. Then filter rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and `sum` per first 2 levels. It lost level `ms`, so is added with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

Last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with filtering rows with inverted mask by `~` and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
mask = df.index.get_level_values('ms') > 12
df1 = df[mask].sum(level=[0,1]).assign(ms='>12').set_index('ms', append=True)

df = pd.concat([df[~mask], df1]).sort_index()
print (df)
               percent
target wt ms          
g1     2  1      2.000
          2      5.000
          >12    0.008
g9     8  1      4.000
          2      8.000
          >12    0.009
```